# jquery file uploader - click event - some magic going on here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with class `.link`.

Jquery file upload upload button is like this -

```
<input id="upload-button-file" multiple="" name="photo" type="file">
```

I have an event when link clicked:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
     debugger;
     $("#upload-button-file").trigger("click"); 
});
```

So, when I click that link with class `.link`, I am being shown a popup to browse images.
But, when I manually run the line

`$("#upload-button-file").trigger("click");`

in console, it is not shwing popup.  Also, if I use debugger as above, if I enter that line during debug, it is not working, but if I execute that line using debugger, it is working.

Please let me know for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the code that displays the popup into a function and call it directly from both events. Take the trigger event out of the equation.

```
showPopup: function() {
  $(#popup).show() // or some code that creates your popup
  //other code
}

$('.link').click(function() {
  showPopup();
}

$('#upload-button-file').click(function() {
  showPopup();
}
```

Or consider,

```
<element id='id' class='class' onclick="Object.showPopup() or new Popup()"></element>
```

You can make the call directly from the html tag.